# Django: IPv4 only for GenericIPAddressField

Tags: python, django

Using Django's `GenericIPAddressField` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#genericipaddressfield for my model like this:

```
group_address = models.GenericIPAddressField()
```

If invalid value is inputted, this returns a message:

```
Enter a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address.
```

Now in my case the field only accepts IPv4 addresses. I would like to remove IPv6 from the message.

Is it possible to tune `GenericIPAddressField` to only handle IPv4 or overwrite the error message?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found out that I have to set `protocol` attribute on the field:

```
group_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4')
```

Now the message looks like:

```
Enter a valid IPv4 address.
```